# chrome bug display flex width 100

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have a little problem with my page.

view : https://user.oc-static.com/upload/2016/12/24/14826126993639_14825671380969_123.png

The problem is that the image is supposed to stay right completely BUT the image moves to the left when I change the resolution of the browser. The problem occurs with Chrome and Internet Explorer (not firefox)

```css
html {
    height: 100%;
    background: black;
}
body {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
table {
    border: 0;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
#container {
    color: white;
    display: flex;
    overflow: hidden;
    height: 100%;
}
#global {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%
    text-align: center;
}
#table {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
#droite {
    height: 100%;
    text-align: right;
}
#image {
    height: 100%;
    display: block;
    width: inherit;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>test</title>

</head>
 
 
<body>
 
  <div id="container">
 
    <div id="global">
      <table id="table">
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td>d</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
 
    <div id="droite">
      <img src="//zagicien.com/test.jpg" alt="" id="image">
    </div>
 
  </div>
 
</body>
 
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**solution**: delete the div with the id "Droite" and keep only the image.

Answer (score 0):

If you add `flex: 1` on the second element and `flex: 0` on the first you should get the result you expect.

https://jsfiddle.net/wrmbh6qc/1/

```css
html {
  height: 100%;
  background: black;
}

body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

table {
  border: 0;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

#container {
  color: white;
  display: flex;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 100%;
}

#global {
/*  width: 100%;*/
  height: 100%;
  text-align: center;
flex: 0;
}

#table {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

#droite {
  height: 100%;
  text-align: right;
flex: 1;
width: -webkit-fill-available;
}

#image {
  height: 100%;
  width: auto;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">

  <div id="global">
    <table id="table">
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>d</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>

  <div id="droite">
    <img src="//zagicien.com/test.jpg" alt="" id="image">
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Interesting, but this still doesn't solve my problem :(

Comment: @user2699190 How does this solution not solve your problem?

Comment: when you resize window of chrome. there are some bugs sometimes. bug of chrome no matter the solution

Comment: Adding `width: -webkit-fill-available;` seems to fix it on Chrome. Updated the answer with it.

Comment: solution: delete the div with the id "Droite" and keep only the image.